# Who viewed a video in Community Portal

Tags: customer-community, video

Can anyone explain how to get analytics about video content I have published in customer portal. I know there is 'Vidyard for Salesforce' available- looking for something else, if there is any way to get this information from the communities itself. For eg, I have posted a youtube video in my customer community and want to know who has clicked on this link and watched it.